# Can I validate Yup type using typescript interface in react-hook-form?

Tags: typescript, typeerror, react-hook-form, yup

I tried to validate Yup object with typescript like below.

```js
        interface IYup {
        num: number[],
        str: string
        }
    
        const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
            num: Yup.array(),
            str: Yup.string()
        })
    
        const methods = useForm<IYup>({resolver: yupResolver<Yup.AnyObjectSchema>(validationSchema)});
        const {register, handleSubmit} = methods;
```

If I write code like below, I want to make type error occur

> Type '{ num: array; str: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IYup'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'number' does not
> exist in type 'IYup'.

```js
        interface IYup {
        num: number[],
        str: string
        }
    
        const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
            num: Yup.array(),
            str: Yup.number()
        })
    
        const methods = useForm<IYup>({resolver: yupResolver<Yup.AnyObjectSchema>(validationSchema)});
        const {register, handleSubmit} = methods;
```

How can I make type error occur using typescript?

> I found potential answers in yup document, but it didn't work as I
> expected.
>
> https://github.com/jquense/yup#typescript-integration